# Override field schema based on data - Marshmallow

Tags: python, validation, flask-restful, marshmallow

I'm just getting started with marshmallow so if there's a more elegant way to solve the issue please let me know. 
Fields will be varied based on the user type (student/staff)

```
{
   "type": "student",   
   "name": "Student 1",
   "class": "V Std",
   "section": "A Class"
}
```

if type `Staff` we need to validate `designation` and `experience` skip `class` and `section`

```
{
   "type": "staff",   
   "name": "Staff 1",
   "designation": "Professor",
   "experience": "2 Year"
}
```

I have the following simple model and schema.

```py
class AddUser(Resource):
   def post(self):
      content = request.get_json(silent=True)
      try:
         data = UserSchema().load(content)       
         print(data)

      except ValidationError as err:
         return err.messages, 400

class UserSchema(Schema):
   type = fields.Str(required=True,validate=OneOf(['student', 'staff'], error='Invalid User Type'), error_messages={'required': 'User type required'})
   name = fields.Str(required=True)
   class = fields.Str()
   section = fields.Str()
   designation = fields.Str()
   experience = fields.Str()

   @post_load
   # @pre_load
   # @validates_schema
   def unwrap_envelope(self, data):   
     student = {
       class: fields.Str(required=True),
       section: fields.Str(required=True)
     }

      staff = {
       designation: fields.Str(required=True),
       experience: fields.Str(required=True)
     }

     # Fields are getting updated but it is **not raising the error**

     if data['type'] == 'student':
       self.declared_fields.update(student)
     elseif data['type'] == 'staff':
       self.declared_fields.update(staff)

     return data
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is polymorphism.

It's not straightforward to achieve and marshmallow does not come with an easy way to do it. You can check [marshmallow-oneofschema](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-oneofschema) and [marshmallow-polyfield](https://github.com/Bachmann1234/marshmallow-polyfield). Those two third-party libraries are meant for that. They both have their pros and cons, so none of them was included in marshmallow core.