# Python marshmallow: how to allow multiple Schemas to a Schema's field?

Tags: python, serialization, polymorphism, marshmallow

I'd like to declare a schema field to accept different schema types, **but not any**.

Is something like the following possible with Marshmallow?

```
class SchemaA(Schema):
    name = String()

class SchemaB(Schema):
    name = String()
    age = Integer()

class SchemaC(Schema)
    one_of_many_but_not_any = [SchemaA(), SchemaB(), String()]  # <- !
```

Comment: Linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092906/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655674/ but your question is much more concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to achieve is referred to as polymorphism.

This is not supported by marshmallow yet but it is a recurrent question and I've been tagging all related issues in the bugtracker with the [polymorphism](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label%3Apolymorphism) tag.

See for instance https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/1255.

There are currently two libs adding this support:

- [marshmallow-oneofschema](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-oneofschema)
- [marshmallow-polyfield](https://github.com/Bachmann1234/marshmallow-polyfield)

They both have their pros/cons.